# Compilation errors setting up Box2D with Cocos2d in Xcode

Tags: xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I notice several other people have had similar problems, however this is a bit strange...

I have a new install of scode 4.2 and the most recent cocos2d from a few weeks back. I have changed all files that include Box2D to the C++ .mm file extension. I have also set a user header search path for appName/libs**.

When I compile either **b2BroadPhase.cpp** and/or **b2CollideCircle.cpp** are missing, or even more rare, **Box2d.h** is missing. I have checked and all of these files are in the correct location in my applications directory.

Can anyone tell me why the files are not being found and why the number of files missing is randomly fluctuating?

EDIT:

Ok, so I obviously don't understand Header Search Paths... Are they designed to point towards folders that wouldn't normally be searched? If I add a Header Search Path then I get 200+ errors saying box2D files cannot be found. If I don't add a header search path I get 1-3 errors saying files cannot be found.

Comment: I keep repeating myself but if you were to use Kobold2D http://www.kobold2d.com you wouldn't have to worry about such "setting up third party library" issues. ;)

Comment: hehehe you've convinced me, I'll check out Kobold2d for my next project. I don't like to jump ship mid way through however :)

Comment: No harm in trying it out. ;) http://kobold2d.com/x/zAMO

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have set the "User Header Search Path". However, Box2D requires you to specify the path in the "Header Search Path" build setting. This is because Box2D is using C++ style angle bracket include statements:

```
#include <Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.h>
```

*If that should not solve the (or all of the) problem(s), check this:*

If you assume the same Box2D path as it is in cocos2d-iphone:

```
cocos2d-iphone/external/Box2d/Box2D
```

Then your Box2D Header Search Path must point to

```
cocos2d-iphone/external/Box2d/Box2D
```

You may have specified the "Box2d" folder instead of the "Box2d/Box2D" folder. That is also a common mistake.

Comment: Hmm I have tried this and its still not working. To be clear, I designated a cocos2d/box2d app from the xcode menu when I started the app, I did not import cocos2d myself. My app folder has a box2D folder and a cocos2d folder in it. So my to get to my box2D folder the address is /appname/appname/libs/Box2D and to get to the cocos2d folder the address is /appname/appname/libs/Box2D.

Comment: sorry, /appname/appname/libs/cococs2d for the cocos2d folder

Answer (score 0):

Your header search paths are most likely wrong. Would you mind posting what it is? 
If your Box2D folder is in your Xcode folder (look in finder), it should be as simple as this:

```
$(SRCROOT)
```

or

```
$(SRCROOT)/Box2D
```

Comment: My box2d folder is located in my application directory. I would post my search paths but im not sure what they are :/ All I have set is a User Header Search Paths is AppName/libs/**. I notice for just Header Search Paths I can set debug and release search paths... is that anything to do with it?

Comment: No just go to your project settings, search for: User Header Search Paths Then type in my first example above. If that doesn't work type in my second example and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have tried those two plus $(SRCROOT)/libs/Box2D and a few others with recursion enabled and I still have the same problem :/

Comment: Do you mind posting a screenshot of where the Box2D folder in located in finder? I just want to make sure I am on the same track as you!

Comment: I can assure you its at $(SRCROOT)/libs/Box2D which contains the Box2D.h file and Collision,Common and Dynamics folders. If thats not enough info I'll take a screenshot.

Comment: I don't want to trouble you too much. Did you try googling this issue? I remember having a similar issue but for me it was the header search path that fixed it.

Comment: Haha don't worry about troubling me, thank you for trying to help! I notice a few people have tried removing cocos2d and adding it again. I'll try that and google header paths some more, then report back if I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was having an #import "Box2D.h" statement on a file with a ".m" extension instead of ".mm"  .. Changing the file extension (select file, press enter, add extra "m") got rid of all the box2d errors.

Hopefully this helps someone else!